# Monitoring text file for changed contents prevents the file from being written

Tags: c#, console-application, updates, inotifypropertychanged

I've a text file and the value in the file is being read into the application (console application).  I want to update the value in the application when the value in the text file is changed. I've referred to this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c4fd8ac1-27b7-4f76-8755-3450e11515cb/inotifypropertychanged-console-sample-program) and done some modification. The result is when I change the value in the text file and try to save it, the value in the application is not updated, because the file cannot be saved.

How can I update the value in the application if I change the value in the text file?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestClass sample = new TestClass();
            sample.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(sample_PropertyChanged);

            while (true)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Testing.txt"))
                {
                    // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                    string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sample.TestValue = str;
                }  
            }
        }

        static void sample_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TestClass sample = (TestClass)sender;
            /*
             * Use expression behind if you have more the one property instead sample.TestValue
             * typeof(TestClass).GetProperty(e.PropertyName).GetValue(sample, null)*/
            Console.WriteLine("Value of property {0} was changed! New value is {1}", e.PropertyName, sample.TestValue);
        }
    }

    public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

        string testValue = string.Empty;
        public string TestValue
        {
            get { return testValue; }
            set
            {
                testValue = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TestValue"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if the loop caused this problem. Can you leverage [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi @qxg, thanks for your comment. In actual environment, the value in the text file will be the value in a configuration application (connected to a config server), I'm able to retrieve the value from the config app, but just can't update the value in my application once the value is changed. For the problem above, I just gave a simple example which similar to the actual one.

Comment: Your code works for me. Check other issues.

Comment: After I run my app, the value keeps looping, and when I change the value in the text file, it doesn't allow me to save because the file is used by another program.

Comment: That's only a file system issue? So the problem is not how do you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (of course, it's good to check if value really changed by comparing old value in `TestValue` property). you have problem on how to read value from another app/server. Please update question if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There at least three serious problems in your code:

1. You are polling incessantly when reading the file, which will leave very little time (essentially none) for any other process to write to the file.
2. You raise the `PropertyChanged` event any time the property setter is called, whether or not the property value actually did change.
3. You are raising the `PropertyChanged` event before you close the file. This unnecessarily extends the period of time the file is left open (indeed, it leaves open the risk that the event handler can force the file to be left open for an arbitrarily long time).

The simplest fixes for the above would look something like this:

```
        while (true)
        {
            string str = File.ReadAllText("Testing.txt");

            sample.TestValue = str;
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // sleep for 1 second
        }
```

and this:

```
    public string TestValue
    {
        get { return testValue; }
        set
        {
            if (testValue != value)
            {
                testValue = value;

                // BUGBUG: Warning! This code is not thread-safe; it is possible for
                // the current thread to check `PropertyChanged` just before some other
                // thread changes its value to null, and then to try to invoke the handler
                // just _after_ that other thread changes its value to null. This is fine
                // if you are sure that the event and property are both only ever accessed
                // in one single thread. But otherwise, you need to fix this bug, by
                // following the normal C# idiom for raising events, i.e. store the field
                // value in a local variable, and then if it's non-null, raise the event
                // using the local variable's value instead of the event field itself.

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TestValue"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Please note the comment in the code above regarding your possible bug in the handling of the event.

Besides that, there are a couple of other refinements you could make to the code:

1. Before actually opening the file, use `File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc()` to check the file modification timestamp for your file, and only open the file to read it if the timestamp is newer than the last time you checked. This will avoid opening the file unnecessarily, reducing the chances of a file lock conflict.
2. Even better, instead of the above, don't poll at all. Let `FileSystemWatcher` do your work for you, and only read the file when the `Changed` event is raised. The main drawback to this is that `FileSystemWatcher` is not always (in fact, not usually) notified on a timely basis of changes to files. It will eventually raise the appropriate event, but it's tracking directory information which is itself not always updated by Windows on a timely basis, causing delays (up to a few dozen seconds, in my experience) in being notified of changes.

If you can accept up to e.g. a minute delay before being notified, then I'd recommend `FileSystemWatcher`. Otherwise, just polling every second (or less frequently), or the #1 option where you at least check the modification timestamp, would be fine.